# Is there a closed form for $n^k$ in terms of $\Delta n^{k+1},\Delta n^k$, ...?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Let $\Delta$ be a sort of difference operator on a function $f(n)$ such that
$$\Delta f(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$$
Take the basic power function $f(n)=n^k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. Then we get
$$\begin{cases}\Delta 1=0\\[1ex]
\Delta n=1\\[1ex]
\Delta n^2=2n+1\\[1ex]
\Delta n^3=3n^2+3n+1
\end{cases}$$
and so on, with the general form
$$\Delta n^k=(n+1)^k-n^k=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom kin^k$$
I'm wondering if there's a parallel closed form for $n^k$ in terms of $\Delta n^{k+1},\Delta n^k,\ldots,\Delta n$? What I mean by this is that for $n$, we can write
$$n=\frac{\Delta n^2}{2}-\frac{\Delta n}{2}$$
since
$$\frac{\Delta n^2}{2}-\frac{\Delta n}{2}=\frac{2n+1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=n$$
Similarly, one can show that
$$\begin{cases}n^2=\dfrac{\Delta n^3}{3}-\dfrac{\Delta n^2}{2}+\dfrac{\Delta n}{6}\\[1ex]
n^3=\dfrac{\Delta n^4}{4}-\dfrac{\Delta n^3}{2}+\dfrac{\Delta n^2}{4}\\[1ex]
n^4=\dfrac{\Delta n^5}{5}-\dfrac{\Delta n^4}{2}+\dfrac{\Delta n^3}{3}-\dfrac{\Delta n}{30}\end{cases}$$
and so on, with no immediate pattern as far as I can tell. **Is there one?**

Comment: It boils down to showing that the linear system (a matrix similar to $a_{ij}={i \choose j}$ for $i \leq j$ and zero otherwise) you have has a nonzero determinant.

Comment: @nayrb: I've added an answer with a different approach which might be interesting. Regards,

Comment: Are you sure, that in the last (=$n^4$) equation the linear term $- \frac {\Delta n}{30}$ is  negative and not positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We  derive  a formula for  $n^k$  in   terms of $\Delta n^k$  by use of *binomial inverse pairs* and their *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)*. We show

> the following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> n^k=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}\Delta n^iB_{k+1-i}\qquad\qquad k\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>   with $B_k$ the *[Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)*.

$$ $$

> We define
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\Delta n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}\qquad\qquad B(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}
> \end{align*}
>
> According to the definition of the $\Delta$ operator we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Delta n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left((n+1)^k-n^k\right)\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i}n^i\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}n^i\frac{x^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left(e^x-1\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=B(x)\left(e^x-1\right)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the multiplication of exponential generating functions
  \begin{align*}
  \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)
  =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}a_i b_{k-i}\right)\frac{x^k}{k!}
  \end{align*}
  with $a_k=n^k$ and $b_k=1$ for all $k\geq 0$.
- In (2) we see the relationship between $\Delta n^k$ und $n^k$ in terms of generating functions.

> From (2) we obtain the generating function $B(x)$ for $n^k$ by the generating function $A(x)$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> B(x)&=A(x)\frac{1}{e^x-1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{x}A(x)\frac{x}{e^x-1}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

In (3) we see the generating function of the *[Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function)*
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{x^k}{k!}
\end{align*}

> and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> B(x)&=\frac{1}{x}A(x)\frac{x}{e^x-1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Delta n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}\Delta n^i B_{k-i}\right)\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> Comparing coefficients of $B(x)$ and the RHS of (4) gives
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{k!}n^k&=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}\Delta n^iB_{k+1-i}\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\qquad\qquad k\geq 0\\
> n^k&=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}\Delta n^iB_{k+1-i}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

**Epilogue** *Binomial inverse pairs*

Let's summarise the result about this binomial inverse pair. We observe the following relationship
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\Delta n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}&B(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n^k\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
&=B(x)\left(e^x-1\right)&&=\frac{1}{x}A(x)\frac{x}{e^x-1}\\
\Delta n^k&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i}n^k&n^k&=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}\Delta n^iB_{k+1-i}
\end{align*}